# Can't Iterate over an ArrayList with c:foreach (JSP/JSTL)

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl, el

So I am getting an ArrayList of `StudentBeans` from the session, and I want to iterate through each `StudentBean` and get the values, but for some reason, the elements of ArrayList are not being stored in the variable as I am getting only one 0 arg constructor `StudentBean`. Can you tell me where is my mistake?

```
    <jsp:useBean
        id="list"
        class="java.util.ArrayList"
        type="java.util.ArrayList"
        scope="session">
    </jsp:useBean>

    <jsp:useBean
        id="student"
        class="com.foo.bar.beans.StudentBean"
        type="com.foo.bar.beans.StudentBean"
        scope="page">
    </jsp:useBean>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="student"> 

            <tr>
                <td>
                    x
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${student.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${student.id}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${student.grade}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: get rid of  this declaration `<jsp:useBean
        id="list"
        class="java.util.ArrayList...."` and rename `<jsp:useBean
        id="student"` to `list`

Comment: Also refer to https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action

Comment: If I remove `<jsp:useBean id="list" class="java.util.ArrayList.....` how will i get list from session?

Comment: Where are you creating your `List` of `StudentBeans` ?  Certainly not by just declaring `<jsp:useBean id="list" class="java.util.ArrayList...."`

Comment: I have a servlet to make ArrayList and store it in the session

Comment: I works fine with for loop and scriptlet tags, but i want to do it with JSTL

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I am not able to do comment.

Have you included the core tag library in your JSP File?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Maybe because of this your variable is not storing.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated *I have a servlet to make ArrayList and store it in the session* lets assume that the session attribute is called `sList`

Then in your JSP all you need is

```
<c:forEach items='${sList}' var='student'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                x
            </td>
            <td>
                ${student.name}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${student.id}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${student.grade}
            </td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```